# Not installing softwares after changing the server

Tags: 12.04, server, apt, mysql

I changed the download server from sri lanka server to US server using software and update window. Then I tried to install mysql using this command.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

It gives me this error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
N: Ignoring file 'google-talkplugin.listsudo' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'google-talkplugin.listsudo' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Unable to locate package mysql-server
```

Then I tried to change the download server back to sri lanka server. But that server has been disappeared in server locations. When I click 'select best server' button It says

```
No suitable download server was found. Please check your internet connection.
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I'm guessing you've already checked your internet connection and DNS resolution.

Comment: @mchid yes. I can ping to web sites using my terminal and browse web pages using browser without having any issue

Comment: BTW and while you're at it, you can change the name of /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-talkplugin.listsudo to "google-talkplugin.list" to get rid of that other error.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the /etc/apt/sources.list file manually. From there, you can change all the servers back to http://mirror.learn.ac.lk/ubuntu . On my desktop, this is listed as the Sri-Lanka mirror. You can use gedit, nano, leafpad, vi, or your favorite text editor to open the file with sudo permissions. Example:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

The file should look like this or roughly similar based upon individual user prefrences.

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://mirror.learn.ac.lk/ubuntu precise main restricted
#deb-src http://mirror.learn.ac.lk/ubuntu precise main restricted
## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://mirror.learn.ac.lk/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted
#deb-src http://mirror.learn.ac.lk/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://mirror.learn.ac.lk/ubuntu precise universe
#deb-src http://mirror.learn.ac.lk/ubuntu precise universe
deb http://mirror.learn.ac.lk/ubuntu precise-updates universe
#deb-src http://mirror.learn.ac.lk/ubuntu precise-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://mirror.learn.ac.lk/ubuntu precise multiverse
#deb-src http://mirror.learn.ac.lk/ubuntu precise multiverse
deb http://mirror.learn.ac.lk/ubuntu precise-updates multiverse
#deb-src http://mirror.learn.ac.lk/ubuntu precise-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://mirror.learn.ac.lk/ubuntu precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-src http://mirror.learn.ac.lk/ubuntu precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://mirror.learn.ac.lk/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
#deb-src http://mirror.learn.ac.lk/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb http://mirror.learn.ac.lk/ubuntu precise-security universe
#deb-src http://mirror.learn.ac.lk/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb http://mirror.learn.ac.lk/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
#deb-src http://mirror.learn.ac.lk/ubuntu precise-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
#deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Ubuntu's
## 'extras' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
#deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

---

Here is a condensed version of that list if it makes it any easier for you. In fact, you don't really need all that other stuff and the file will function the same with just these lines:

```
deb http://mirror.learn.ac.lk/ubuntu precise main restricted
deb http://mirror.learn.ac.lk/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted

deb http://mirror.learn.ac.lk/ubuntu precise universe
deb http://mirror.learn.ac.lk/ubuntu precise-updates universe

deb http://mirror.learn.ac.lk/ubuntu precise multiverse
deb http://mirror.learn.ac.lk/ubuntu precise-updates multiverse

deb http://mirror.learn.ac.lk/ubuntu precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://mirror.learn.ac.lk/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb http://mirror.learn.ac.lk/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb http://mirror.learn.ac.lk/ubuntu precise-security multiverse

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

Comment: By following your answer part of the problem has been resolved. I replaced the /etc/apt directory with another folder copied from my other computer. Thank you for guiding me to the solution.

Comment: @Asanka No prob. Was the server the correct one or is it different for 12.04?

Comment: yes. I'm having another ubuntu 12.04 installed server